# A project's resource dll is not being copied to build directory

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, dll, resources

I have a solution which includes many projects.

One of these projects, let's call it Wilson, creates 2 DLLs when built: wilson.dll and fr/wilson.resources.dll. I can find both these files in myStuff/Wilson/bin/Debug/.

When I build my solution in myStuff/mySolution/, wilson.dll gets copied to myStuff/mySolution/App_Data/Dependencies.

However, wilson.resources.dll doesn't get copied over. Because of this, any resource strings from the project are not translated.

If I manually copy wilson.resources.dll from Wilson's bin/Debug/fr/ directory into my solution's App_Data/Dependencies/fr/ directory, everything works.

How can I get Visual Studio to copy over fr/wilson.resources.dll with wilson.dll ?

---

**More info:**

I have mySolution open, under Solution Explorer I can find the Wilson project, and also the Alpha project.

Under the Wilson project, the Resources.fr.resx file is set to "Copy to Output Directory : Copy always".

Under the Alpha project, under References, the reference to Wilson is set to "Copy Local: True".

It's still not working.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the file properties (select file on solution explorer, project References folder, and press F4, or right click on it to show them). Fin "Copy Local" and set it to true.

If it's nos included as a reference, the property to set will be "Copy to output directory".

Comment: I don't believe this is the solution here. Resource DLL's are generated by compiling a project that includes multiple resources, for example `StringResources.resx`, `StringResources.fr.resx`, etc. They are not made by specifically including a reference.

Comment: I have mySolution open, under Solution Explorer I can find the Wilson project, and also the Alpha project.

Under the Wilson project, the Resources.fr.resx file is set to "Copy to Output Directory : Copy always".

Under the Alpha project, under References, the reference to Wilson is set to "Copy Local: True".



It's still not working.

Comment: @KevBelisle which is the main project type? Is it a web site or a web application?

Comment: I believe it's a Web Application. The "mySolution" I'm referring to is actually Orchard.Web (a CMS written in C#). "Alpha" is a module that uses "Wilson" to access data from our DB. "Wilson" is also used in other solutions (e.g. an API for our mobile app).

Comment: How does the web app or site looks like? is it like a world globe or like a page with a littel globe in front of it? If you right click on the project does it have a regular "properties" option as any other project or a "Property pages" option that opens a dialog?

Comment: It's a page with a little globe in front of it. When I right click, there is a "Properties" option. http://i.imgur.com/DNuFu4m.jpg